# Make a list of an unknown number of items stretch to full width of container, responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of an unknown number of items. The container has a border top that shows the width.

No matter the browser size (responsive) the list items should occupy all the width of the container. Currently, as you can see, there is a space to the right of the container. The last `li` item of a row should be in line with the end of the border.

How can it be done without a lot of media queries?
End result as the image bellow. Basically the thing that should change on resize is the space between list items..

[image]

Thanks!

```css
.Container{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
#list{
  padding:20px 0 0 0;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  width:50%;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">

    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
    <li class="Container"></li>
  
</ul
```

Comment: You can realise this using the CSS3 flexbox model, if the browser support of it is ok for you: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox
This would likely be the easiest solution.

Comment: @MichaelWagner Yes, don't care about IE on small things like this. Thanks, will look into it

Comment: What about prime numbers? What if there are 23 items? There will always be a floater unless you're cool with uneven spacing among rows.

Comment: I don't know flexbox exactly, but I think it can position all elements in a container in a row using flex-direction. Please correct my if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a flex solution:

```
#list{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding:20px 0 0 0;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  width:30%;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.Container{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

This works for all rows except the last one:

[image]

A fix is to add *additional* elements, with visibility hidden:

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

<li class="Container hidden"></li>
<li class="Container hidden"></li>
...
```

Since elements with `visibility: hidden` still take up screen space, the flex box will take them into account during layout:

[image]

In [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/78075paj/), the elements stay evenly spaced as you grow and shrink the viewport.

Comment: Thanks mate, was trying but with no avail to fix the last row.

Comment: Yes, that was tough for me to figure out.  I haven't seen that as a solution elsewhere.